# SSMS 2014 can't deploy databases to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to deploy my sql server 2014 database to SQL Azure using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2014 and i get the following error:

[image]

I selected a Business edition while selecting which SQL Edition in the Sql deploy Wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to deploy to the Business tier, it's now retired. The wizard may not be updated to reflect this change. The tier that you will want to select for similar performance is probably one of the Standard tiers, but Premium is also available. For more information, view https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-introduces-new-service-tiers/

Upon further checking (see below) it seems that the tools are not upgraded to reflect the current tiers. So the problem is with SSMS in this case.

Comment: Thanks Amanda! The SSMS UI is behind for the available tiers we have in Azure Portal. The wizard allows only Web and Business editions! Both are not available in Azure Portal. I am trying to find out what is the compatible edition that allow devs to deploy dbs from SSMS to Azure with no error. Tries are happening now...

Comment: Upgrading to the higher tiers didn't work either. So the SSMS tools need an update to work with the latest Azure tiers.

Comment: Thanks for the further information. I'll add this to the answer to clarify.